What is this usage of 以前に?

何よりそれに対してずっと足掻いてきたのは自分だ。こんな男の前で、その通りだなどと正誤以前に絶対に答えたくはない。

The character is asked a question regarding his status as a cursed being. However the character doesn't want to answer, regardless or whatever the other's opinion may be correct or not, as he dislikes the other person.
I understand the sentence is "above else, when it comes to that, I was the one who struggled." and then "I don't want to answer him"
I'm a bit unsure, what does "、その通りだなどと正誤以前に" mean here?
"before saying that's right"?

以前に is quite commonly used to mean something other than just "before" in the temporal sense: see https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/70307/this-use-of-%e4%bb%a5%e5%89%8d%e3%81%ab and https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/30664/usage-of-%e4%bb%a5%e5%89%8d-here
This usage doesn't seem to be very well documented in dictionaries though...

The sentence may be a little easier to understand if the word order is changed like this:

正誤以前に、その通りだなどと絶対に答えたくはない。

This roughly means "Before even considering whether it's correct or wrong, I absolutely don't want to respond with something like "That's correct".
The speaker is saying that he is never going to admit the opinion regardless of whether it's correct or incorrect, so it's not a problem of the opinion's correctness.
